# String Manipulation: format a string to have last three are numbers in C#

Tags: string, c#-4.0

I recently gone through a programming contest and asked to write below program.

Puzzle (String Manipulation):
1. Your function takes a string and returns a string.
2. String input ex:
    1. 0AB1CD   -> return value shall be "0AB1CD000"
    2. 0AB1CD6   -> return value shall be "0AB1CD006"
    3. 0AB1CD26   -> return value shall be "0AB1CD026"

3. The function shall make sure last three are digits. If not, need to make three numbers by padding 0's to the left.
4. DO NOT USE REGULAR EXPRESSION

Tried:
1. I did validation for Empty String, All Numbers, Spaces.
2. After that, I took last three characters from string and checked whether they are characters or numbers.

Loop through three characters with Char.IsNumeric() function: 
  a. Assign boolean for each position
  b. If all three are characters, append "000" to the string.
  c. If first and second booleans are false, append "00" to the string (before the last found number) 
  d. If all are numbers, return the string.

This method might yield the result, but I am sure is not optimized and there will be a better solution.

Please can you help me how to do it better with and without regular expression?

Regards,
Raju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending `"00"` and `"0"` won't give the correct result. For the string `"0AB1CD26"` that would give you `"0AB1CD260"` instead of `"0AB1CD026"`.

You can loop through the characters from the end of the string, and count until you reach a non-digit or the count 3:

```
int cnt = 0;
while (cnt < 3 && Char.IsNumeric(str[str.Length - 1 - cnt])) {
  cnt++;
}
```

Then you can insert the correct number of zeroes at the correct position:

```
if (cnt < 3) {
  str = str.Insert(str.Length - cnt, new String('0', 3 - cnt));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Guffa. Upvoted the answer but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.